# Very large MySQL database, deleted a column, and the size of the database increased by 50%

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a 20gb MySQL database which contains about 30 million rows of data in one table. I wanted to delete a column within that table to clear up some space.

I dropped the column via phpMyAdmin which took about 15 minutes and checked the disk usage in my server. It went from 20gb to 28gb used after deleting a column that was filled with data.

Did I do something wrong? Am I missing something obvious?

I did nothing else while I was trying to delete the column.

**Update**: Actually, when I go to the database summary page that lists the tables in phpMyAdmin, it also lists their size. The size of the tables only adds up to 10gb.

When I check the size being used on my server via df -h it says /dev/vda is using 28gb.

The only other files on the server are a few small PHP files. What is taking up this 18gb gap?

Comment: This would probably be a better fit on [dba.se]

Comment: I'm not sure here but I guess it's possible phpmyadmin had a cached estimate for the size of the database that wasn't up to date, and when you deleted the column maybe it recalculated the size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely explanation is that you are not using file-per-table mode, and the `ibdata1` file that contains all tables and indexes increased during the ALTER TABLE. When you delete a column, MySQL has to create a new copy of the table, move all the data into it (minus the column you deleted) and then drop the original table. Near the end of this process, two copies of the table (minus the column you deleted in one copy) need to be stored simultaneously. Then when that's complete, it drops the original copy and that space can be reused in the future.

Unfortunately, there's [no way to shrink the ibdata1](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1341). It remains at a size equal to its high-water mark. To recover the disk space, you have to:

1. Dump all InnoDB tables (or convert them to MyISAM temporarily)
2. Shut down MySQL Server
3. Remove ibdata1 and ib_logfile*
4. Set `innodb_file_per_table=1` in your my.cnf
5. Restart. The missing ibdata1 will be created at the initial default size.
6. Import your data.

Now the tables will occupy a separate file per table. When you ALTER or OPTIMIZE them, they will recover space. This mode is enabled by default in MySQL 5.6.

Comment: How do I check the status of innodb_file_per_table? Major linux noob here. NM, found it in PhpMyAdmin. It's set to off. This is probably the issue then. I've got a good backup so I'll give it a shot...

Comment: Just navigated to /var/lib/mysql which is where ibdata1 is stored. That file is 19.7gb. Plus the 9gb that phpMyAdmin says my database actually is, and there's the 28gb that's in use. Once I fix it I'll mark your comment as the answer. Thanks!